# How to get Grails HeaderParam attributes

Tags: java, grails

I came for ruby/rails background. I am facing issues to get header attributes of rest call.

In case of rails, I used to write below code to list all requested header attributes.

```
puts request.headers.inspect
```

Could any body please suggest me what is the equivalent for Grails ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the code, which list all header attributes.

```
 request.headerNames.each{
   println it
 }
```

attributes

```
accept
accept-encoding
content-type
api-key
time-stamp
signature
user-agent
```

host

Comment: From my ruby client, sending header params using underscore ( :api_key => params['api_key'], :time_stamp => params['time_stamp'])

Dn't know why grails server reflection underscore with hyphen(-)

Comment: Above problem is with only HeaderParam, QueryParam is fine.

Answer (score 9):

The [request object](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html) is an instance of the Servlet API's [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/8/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) interface, so you can use the `getHeader` and `getHeaderNames` methods

This is an example of how to print all the headers - add it where you can access the `request` object (e.g. inside a controller method):

```
request.getHeaderNames().each {        
    println(it + ":" + request.getHeader(it))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Servlet%20API/request.html). On this page you can find "The request object is an instance of the Servlet API's [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) interface". You can use `getHeader` and `getHeaderNames` methods

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember in Groovy/Grails any getXXX method will treat XXX as a property. So, getHeader and getHeaderNames can be abbreviated to request.header 'someheadername' or request.headerNames